# Expo (React Native) with firebase 9.6.11 "Missing or insufficient permissions"

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm using Firebase version 9.6.11 in a Expo project. The Authentication works perfect, but when I use Firebase Firestore a get the error "Missing or insufficient permissions". I changed the rules of firebase to:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

In a project with React.js it's working, but in React Native with Expo (version 46.0.9) not working. Anyone knows how to solve it?

My config in Expo is:

```js
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { API_KEY, AUTH_DOMAIN, PROJECT_ID, STORAGE_BUCKET, MESSAGING_SENDER_ID, APP_ID } from "@env"

import {
  initializeAuth,
  getReactNativePersistence
} from 'firebase/auth/react-native';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: API_KEY,
  authDomain: AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: APP_ID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// initialize auth
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
});

// initialize firestore
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { auth, db };
```

Comment: Have you already tried upgrading your Firebase version to the latest?

Comment: The latest version of firebase doesn't work well in Expo. Anyway, I just deleted the project in the firebase console, created another one and it worked. It could have been some bug or configuration of my project